# Why do I receive a 404 error when displaying images

Tags: html, image, display

I'm trying to display an img and receive the 404 error. I can see the images locally however when I move it to test I receive the error. From reading other post what I am doing should work.

`<img border="0" src="../images/todaysair.png"   width="10%" alt="Today's Air Quality Conditions"/>`

Comment: Most likely this path is not correct: `../images/todaysair.png`

Comment: Add more information, where is actually your file located, can you open it manually using url, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine, try playing with the src field. compare the image path and where you're putting this line of code.